# VS Code Sidebar Foreground Color Dimmed (Using FireFly Pro Midnight)

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes

The foreground color of some text in my VS Code sidebar is randomly darkened out. Often, these files are files I am actively working with, and it's very difficult to navigate.

I am currently using FireFly Pro Midnight, and the only customization I have is a change to the foreground color to brighten it. The issue occurs whether I change the foreground color or not.

Does anyone know of a good way to change this coloring or the reason it is dimming out certain file names?

[Darkened Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoPFD.png)

[My Only Customization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hins2.png)

Answer (score 0):

This might not be your solution, but here's what worked for me. I had the Git color status activated in my sidebar, so the title of modified files were displayed as dark blue, untracked files as dark green, and ignored files (listed in `.gitignore`) as almost grayish-transparent.

The ignored files were the one causing the problem, so here's [the fix using theme color customization](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#git-colors).

Go to Preferences > Open Settings (JSON), then add this custom block:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "gitDecoration.ignoredResourceForeground": "#949494" // dark gray, but not faded
}
```